# Confusion over Haskell "Nothing" value

Tags: haskell, option-type

I have recently started diving into Haskell. Its quite interesting, but the definition of `Nothing` baffles me and is not sinking in. On GHCI

```
Prelude> :t Nothing
Nothing :: Maybe a
```

Shouldn't `Nothing` be `Just Nothing`, why `Maybe a`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is the definition of the `Maybe` type:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

This states that for some type `a`, the type `Maybe a` has two constructors: `Nothing` and `Just a` (`a` being the same type variable that `Maybe` is applied to on the LHS).

Hopefully it's clear how `Just "foo"` has type `Maybe String` and `Just 'c'` has type `Maybe Char`. But what type is `Nothing`? Since `Nothing` doesn't contain any value, its constructor doesn't use the `a` type variable, and therefore there's nothing that constrains its type to a particular form of `Maybe`.

That makes it a "polymorphic constant". `Nothing` can be used in a context in which any `Maybe` type is expected, because it works equally well in all of them. That's why GHCi reports its type as simply `Maybe a`: the `a` is a variable which could represent any type, and which type it refers to will be determined by inference based on the context in which the `Nothing` value is used. But when you give `Nothing` by itself, there are no additional clues about its specific type, so you just see the variable.

```
> :t Nothing
Nothing :: Maybe a
> :t (Nothing :: Maybe Int)
(Nothing :: Maybe Int) :: Maybe Int
> :t (Nothing :: Maybe Char)
(Nothing :: Maybe Char) :: Maybe Char
```

And by the way, `Just Nothing :: Maybe (Maybe a)`; it's a `Maybe` wrapped in another `Maybe`.

Comment: And just since I remember this not sinking in right away when I was just starting out: The capitalized name (`Maybe`) to the left of the `=` *is only found in type signatures*, whereas the names to the right of the `=` are *only found in code*. By convention, and because the meaning can never be ambiguous, for single-constructor types, often the type constructor will have the same name as its type. I think this is confusing op.

Answer (score 6):

`Maybe` is defined

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

so `Nothing` is a (parameterless) value constructor of the type `Maybe a`, for all `a`, and the value it denotes can belong to all types `Maybe a`, be they `Maybe Bool`, `Maybe [IO (Int,Char)]` or whatever `a` is instantiated with.

Answer (score 4):

`Maybe` is defined as

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

So it can either be `Nothing` or `Just a`. `Mayba a` is the type and `Nothing` and `Just a` are value constructors. `Just Nothing` would be a maybe wrapped inside a maybe, i.e. `Maybe (Maybe a)`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider Scala, which has subtyping. Its equivalent to `Nothing` is called `None`. `None` has type `None`, which is a *subtype* of `Option[a]`. Scala's equivalent to `Just` is `Some(foo)`, which has type `Some[Foo]`, which is a *subtype* of `Option[Foo]`. Haskell does not have subtyping, and therefore types both of them as their common supertype, since this is the most useful typing for them.